# Consumir dados e fazer Formulário Dinâmico com o React

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Preciso consumir os dados de um webservice para criar uma interface de formulário para preenchimento dinâmica, ou seja, que deva se adaptar a estrutura do formulário recebida pelo webservice e não ser fixa com as questões dele.

Como é a primeira vez que mexo em React, passei os últimos dias mergulhado na documentação e em video-aulas, e pensei em resolver o problema do seguinte modo:

- Consumir os dados do webservice usando a biblioteca do axios.
- Passar os dados recebidos para uma variável.
- Utilizar a função `map()` para percorrer essa variável (que será um Array), dentro do meu Componente React.
- Ir preenchendo dinamicamente a interface do formulário.

Infelizmente, não sei o que está dando de errado, se o problema é com a minha metodologia ou com o meu código... vou mostrar o código aqui pra vocês do componente Form, que criei para ser essa interface.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FormTitle from './form-title'
import FormTextInput from './form-text-input'
import FormDateInput from './form-date-input'
import FormStarInput from './form-star-input'
import axios from 'axios'

class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.formInfo = (axios.get("https://coletum.com/api/graphql?query={form_structure(formId:6950){label,componentId,type,helpBlock,order,components}}&token=7s5txcu909kwc48wookgw8g00occokk")
    .then(response => {
      this.formInfo = response.data.data.form_structure 
      console.log(this.formInfo)
      return this.formInfo
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
    )
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <FormTitle>Cadastro de Pokémon</FormTitle>
            <hr/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7">
            <form>
                {this.formInfo.map(i => (
                  <div key={i} className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-label" htmlFor={i.componentId}>{i.label}</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-8">
                    <FormTextInput componentId={i.componentId} />
                    <small className="form-text">{i.helpBlock}</small>
                  </div>
              </div>
                ))}
                

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Form
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Considerando que foi a primeira vez que lidei com React, já considero um pequeno milagre ter chegado até aí.

**Meu problema é** que eu consigo, pelo axios, jogar o array pro meu atributo `this.formInfo`... no entanto, ao tentar usar o método `map()` nesse atributo, ele dá um erro. Eu até preferiria usar o `for in`, em vez do `map()`, mas eu não sei como percorrer esse array com o `for in` dentro da estrutura de renderização do React.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual erro que você recebe ao tentar usar map?

Comment: @JustCase , ele diz **Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**. Quando dou o `console.log(this.formInfo)`, dentro do .then do get do axios, ele me retorna corretamente um array de 5 objetos. No entanto, parece que ele não está passando esse valor pro atributo this.formInfo quando fica fora do axios. Não consigo entender o motivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo a operação no lugar errado, dessa forma o seu render não vai atualizar após terminar a busca. Vc precisa de uma [variável de state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state) (pode ser a 'formInfo') e fazer a busca dentro de um [hook de ciclo de vida](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) do React. Outra coisa é que vc não pode alterar essa variável diretamente, se não o "render" continua não sendo chamado depois de a busca terminar, vc precisa [utilizar o this.setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) para isso.

Observe a mudança no seu constructor e a adição do método componentDidMount

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FormTitle from './form-title'
import FormTextInput from './form-text-input'
import FormDateInput from './form-date-input'
import FormStarInput from './form-star-input'
import axios from 'axios'

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      formInfo: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    axios.get("https://coletum.com/api/graphql?query={form_structure(formId:6950){label,componentId,type,helpBlock,order,components}}&token=7s5txcu909kwc48wookgw8g00occokk")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          formInfo: response.data.data.form_structure 
        })
        console.log(this.formInfo)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <FormTitle>Cadastro de Pokémon</FormTitle>
            <hr/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7">
            <form>
                {this.formInfo.map(i => (
                  <div key={i} className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-label" htmlFor={i.componentId}>{i.label}</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-8">
                    <FormTextInput componentId={i.componentId} />
                    <small className="form-text">{i.helpBlock}</small>
                  </div>
              </div>
                ))}
                

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Form
```

Comment: Cara, fantástico! Funcionou! Muito obrigado! Se não for incômodo pra você, eu gostaria de fazer uma última pergunta. Eu consigo fazer uma condicional dentro do meu render? Por exemplo, se o `type` dentro do meu array for "0", o Componente inserido no render será o de Text. Se o `type` for "1", será o de Data, e etc? Dá pra fazer algo assim só com o If?

Comment: Maravilha! Consegue sim, nesse caso dá pra vc fazer com um ternário, assim:

{this.formInfo.map((value, index) => (
    <div key={index} className="form-group row">
      <label className="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-label" htmlFor={i.componentId}>{i.label}</label>
      <div className="col-sm-8">
        {
          (value.type === 0)
            ? <FormTextInput componentId={i.componentId} />
            : <FormDateInput componentId={i.componentid} />
        }
        <small className="form-text">{i.helpBlock}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}

Comment: Aaah, não dá com o if, mas dá com o ternário! Que massa, é verdade! Mas aninhar ternário é meio ruim... vou ter que pensar num jeito, porque eu tenho pelo menos 4 tipos distintos de inputs. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Vc pode ter uma função e controlar isso dentro dela, digamos que você tenha um método "renderField" dentro da sua classe, você pode passar o type como parâmetro e criar a sua lógica lá dentro.

{this.formInfo.map(i => (
  <div key={i} className="form-group row">
  <label className="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-label" htmlFor={i.componentId}>
    {i.label}
  </label>
  <div className="col-sm-8">
    { this.renderField(i.type) }
    <small className="form-text">{i.helpBlock}</small>
  </div>
</div>
  ))}

Comment: É uma estrutura interessante também! Eu acabei solucionando usando ternários de um só resultado, como, por exemplo  { se o tipo for '1' ? use type="text" : null }, e fiz os 4 seguidos, só mudando o tipo. Como só haverá um campo de tipo em cada objeto dentro do array, não tem como retornar mais que um, então ele passa pelos 4 testes, retornando um tipo e 3 nulls. Mas essa idéia da função é bem interessante também! Obrigado pela dica!